# Search specific file in external storage

Tags: android

I'm developing an APP, and it uses the Read External memory to read an .db file.

Currently I have a Shared Preferences which can be modified to point to the location of that file in external storage.

I have the steps:

1. When the app launch in first time, locate the file based in Shared Preferences setting.
2. If the file not found, search for it in background.
3. If found it, update the location in shared preferences and continue loading the app.
4. If not found it just load a view with a sad face.

My question:
How do I accomplish step 2 (search for a file named my-file.db in external storage)? so I may perform step 3

Edited:
Added the actual working method, but now it don't return the location.

```
//Try to search the DB:

...
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/";
            Files fileLocation = new Files();
            String location = fileLocation.searchDB(path);
            Log.e("elBacheAPP DATA", "FileName:" + location);

            //No DatabaSe was Found!!!
            setContentView(R.layout.no_database);
            toolbarTitle = "No hay Datos";
...

public String searchDB(String path) {

        File directory = new File(path);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();

        if (files != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                //Found it!
                if (files[i].getName().equals("elbacheapp.db")) {
                    Log.e("elBacheAPP DB Found", "FileName:" + files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    String location = new String(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    return location;
                }
                searchDB(path + files[i].getName());
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

This is the output:

```
12-26 22:13:41.829 7420-7420/com.bachecubano.elbache E/elBacheAPP DB Found!: FileName:/storage/emulated/0/testing/elbacheapp.db
12-26 22:13:41.829 7420-7420/com.bachecubano.elbache E/elBacheAPP: Location:/storage/emulated/0/testing/elbacheapp.db
12-26 22:13:41.832 7420-7420/com.bachecubano.elbache E/elBacheAPP DATA: FileName:
```

Comment: "If not found it just load a view with a sad face".  :love:

Comment: so is it fair to assume, that you dont know how to read shared prefs, how to load the file, how to search for it, and also how to update shared prefs?

Comment: I know how to read shared prefs and write it. But don't know how find specific file named "elbacheapp.db" in external storage.

Comment: cool, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: `When the app launch in first time, locate the file based in Shared Preferences setting.` ??? At first launch shared preferences is empty. So there is nothing to base on i would think.

Comment: Yes but remember you can load a Shared Preferences value, and if it is not set, then load a default one, in this case a default location. But sometimes the customers put the db in another location. So that first time could be a great momento for find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first questions would be,

1. Why are you storing your DB in external storage, as opposed to your app's internal (private) storage?
2. Why don't you know the path of your DB?

What being said, you can use [File.list()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#list(java.io.FilenameFilter)) recursively starting from [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) to locate the file of interest. I'll leave the details of that up to you, but it's going to go something like,

```
find(File f) {
  if (f is a file) {
    if (f is the file of interest) { 
      yes: do the work
    }
  else if (f is a dir) {
    for (f2 in f) { find(f2); }
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand your questions. The *.db file is not generated from the app itself. But is a file downloaded from internet and some user put in the root of internal memory, others put in a subfolder, others in external. etc.

Comment: When a file is downloaded, it goes in the `Downloads` folder. Can't you just look there? Are you saying the users download a DB file then go in with a file manager app and move the `.db` file to an arbitrary location in external storage?

Comment: No, I live in Cuba, here the internet is a problem. So, the users get that db file from a alternative network, pendrives, Zapya shares, etc.Sounds funny but it's a reality.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey Blattman, I just added a working method, but now when I try to manipulate the String return it comes empty. ???